# Role-Based Authorization with NodeJS/Express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, authorization, passport.js

I am working on a NodeJS/express application using passportJS for sign in/sign up. I have defined a user model for all users, but want only certain users within my administration to have access to editing certain models. I was thinking of adding a boolean field, like **isAdmin** to determine this, but I don't know how I would verify admin users. To be specific, how would I determine when I need to generate a token for the admin user? How do I differentiate users in my administrations from ordinary users?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is add that field to the JWT payload when they log in and then make a middleware function that checks for that as the second parameter of the route...

---

So let's say this is your schema `User.js`:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 50
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 255,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 1024
  },
  isAdmin: Boolean
});
```

---

This is where you're generating the JWT token:

---

```
userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function() { 
  return jwt.sign({ _id: this._id, isAdmin: this.isAdmin }, config.get('jwtPrivateKey'));
}
```

---

Here is the middleware to check if isAdmin is true:

---

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) { 
  if (!req.user.isAdmin) return res.status(403).send('Access denied.');
  next();
}
```

---

And then you can include it as the second argument to the route handler... So for a PUT it would be something like:

---

```
router.put('/:id', [auth, isAdmin, any other middleware...], async (req, res) => {
 // handle the route...
});
```

---

Comment: How would I determine when to generate the auth token? I only want members in my organization to be able to have admin access.

Comment: How are you handling registering and logging in now?

Comment: Currently, all users can log in using their Google account. (I'm using PassportJS)

Comment: It would have been good to know that beforehand... in order to get a more concrete answer you need to provide the relevant code for your project but the idea is the same... include isAdmin in the schema and a middleware that checks if the person logging in isAdmin or not that gets passed to the route handler...

Comment: That still doesn't answer my question. How would I determine **when** I need to generate the token? How do I differentiate users in my administrations from ordinary users?